Unknown NamedGroup in key_share from Google Chrome
My server has got key_share externsions while TLC 1.3 handshaking:
1 19018 = 0x4a4a = GREASE - OK.
2 25497 = 0x6399 - OpenSSL has not recognized it and written- UNKNOWN...
3 29 - OK
The question is - what extension #2 did I get ?
OpenSSL dump:
extension_type=key_share(51), length=1263
1-NamedGroup: UNKNOWN (19018)
key_exchange:  (len=1): 00
2-NamedGroup: UNKNOWN (25497)
key_exchange:  (len=1216): 5037ABF5A62426676DFA51365E9575936EA416A71CAEC3DA0...
3 - NamedGroup: ecdh_x25519 (29)
key_exchange:  (len=32): D97B685698D8AEA150DEB26FD7C658B3C1A25FAE9EE9A16B40DA3FE6D0020958

Please do some minimal research first. A quick search for name group 0x6399 shows that this is X25519Kyber768.


The question is - what extension #2 did I get ?

This is the proposed Postquantum group X25519Kyber768Draft00 - see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-tls-westerbaan-xyber768d00/02/
This is a combination of X25519 along with Kyber 768 (as of the version 3 draft of the Kyber proposal to NIST).

Poncho, thank you very much! Probably, my search attempts were unsuccessful
